# Getting No such column error on PlatformEventChannel

Tags: rest-api, tooling-api, platform-event

I'm following documentation for integrating salesforce with AWS event bridge ([HERE](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.ev_relay_create_channel_pe.htm&type=5#:%7E:text=CLICKS%2C%20NOT%20CODE-,Create%20a%20Channel%20for%20a%20Custom%20Platform%20Event,-Create%20a%20channel)), but when I try to create a platform event channel With this payload:

> {   "FullName": "SalesEvents__chn",   "Metadata": {
> "channelType": "data",
> "label": "My Custom Channel"   } }

I get

> [
> {
> "message": "No such column 'FullName' on sobject of type PlatformEventChannel",
> "errorCode": "INVALID_FIELD"
> }
> ]

I'm not sure why this is. I'm using the exact endpoint and payload from their given example. Also when I call /services/data/v59.0/sobjects/PlatformEventChannel/describe/ I get a 404 back. Do I have to manually create this object?

Comment: Can you try using v58.0?